# GraphQL field with space

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to use a new GraphQL server on a very old legacy code, where the column names have spaces, e.g: "Poke ball"

I've been trying to run this query:

```
query{{userItems{Poke ball}}}
```

and got this:

```
extensions: {code: "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",…}
locations: [{line: 1, column: 12}]
message: "Cannot query field "Poke" on type "UserItems"."
```

I've tried to use quotes with no luck, any idea if this is supported / workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: use valid names in graphql, map internally to invalid in middleware/resolvers/orm/custom directives ... depends on server specific requirements/possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GraphQL specification](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Names) requires that names of things (fields, types, arguments, etc.) only contain letters, numbers and underscores. A field name cannot contain a space because spaces and other [whitespace](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-White-Space) are used to separate individual tokens. In other words, one or more spaces or line returns are used to indicate that, for example, one field's name has terminated and another has begun.

If your underlying data layer is returning data with keys that contain spaces, you need to define a field with an allowed name (like `pokeball`) and then write a resolver for that field. For example:

```
const UserItems = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "UserItems",
  fields: () => ({
    pokeball: {
      type: Pokeball,
      resolve: (parent) => {
        // The parent value will be whatever the parent field resolved to.
        // We look for a property named "Poke ball" on that value and return it.
        return parent["Poke ball"];
      },
    },
    ...
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

or in the schema, do this

```
directive @fetch(from : String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

type Product {
    Pokeball : String @fetch(from:"Poke ball")
}
```